# Issue restricting Kendo textbox to decimal values

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I used this method for restricting user for typing decimals  in kendo-numeric-textbox. It works but it updates the last value when I click other number. I didn't update last value.For example If i enter 12.678 and after this 8 i enter a 6 or any number its update the last digit and display 12.676.How to solve this error

```
$("#tonnage").kendoNumericTextBox({
  format: "n3",
  decimals: sessionStorage.getItem("weightDecimal"),
  restrictDecimals: true,
  min: 0
});

var ton = $("#tonnage").on("keypress", function() {
  restrictDecimals(ton);
})

restrictDecimals: function(ton) {
  if (isNaN(ton.val())) {
    ton.val(0);
  }

  if (ton.val().indexOf(".") > -1 && (ton.val().split('.')[1].length >= (sessionStorage.getItem("weightDecimal"))) {
      ton.val(ton.val().substring(0, ton.val().length - 1));
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please answer me if anyone view this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably what you are after: 
https://dojo.telerik.com/UZUwEXOk

All I am doing is restricting the textbox to 3 decimal places so any input after this value will not be registered until you delete one of the values in the decimal section. I have also applied the format for the text box to show the 3 decimal places on the screen.

So you should be able to remove the event you have added onto the textbox.

More info can be found via this link [Restirct Decimals API for Numeric TextBox](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/restrictdecimals)